# SWFUpload image upload fails on PHP with 'Partial File Uploaded'

Tags: php, linux, flash, file-upload, swfupload

Okay, so this is a tough one, I've spent hours looking for a solution/problem. I'm using SWFUpload to upload images without reloading the page (with a fancy progressbar too), this works fine when I'm on localhost (Wamp server), but it goes nuts when I try to do so on my real linux server (which is the only possible flag as far as I could see), it's running Apache2 and PHP5. As I said the front-end is fine (apart maybe from the fact it's flash).
The back-end code is as follows:

SWFUpload_settings.js

```
var swfu_settings ={upload_url  : "upload.php",
                flash_url   : "flash/swfupload.swf",
                button_placeholder_id   : "upload_flash",
                file_size_limit : "2 MB",
                file_types  : "*.gif;*.jpg;*.png",
                file_post_name  :   "Filedata",
                file_queue_limit    :   1,
                post_params     :   {
                        "PHPSESSID" : getCookie()
                },
                upload_start_handler    : upload_start,
                upload_error_handler    : upload_error,
                upload_complete_handler : upload_complete,
                upload_progress_handler : upload_progress,
                file_queued_handler :   file_queued,
                button_disabled : false,
                button_width : 120, 
                button_height : 22,
                button_text : '<div class="adm_upload">Select image</div>',
                button_text_style : '.adm_upload{color:#ff0000;}'
                };
```

upload.php

```
function manageUpload(){
        if( isset($_FILES['Filedata']) ){
            $dest_dir = $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/images/products";
            $destination =  $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/images/products/" . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
            if( is_dir($dest_dir) ){
                if( is_writable($dest_dir) ){
                    if( !move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $destination ) ){
                        $html_body = '<h1>File upload error!</h1>';
                        switch ($_FILES['Filedata']['error']) {
                            case 1:
                                $html_body .= 'The file is bigger than this PHP installation allows';
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                $html_body .= 'The file is bigger than this form allows';
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                $html_body .= 'Only part of the file was uploaded';
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                $html_body .= 'No file was uploaded';
                                break;
                            default:
                                $html_body .= 'unknown errror';
                        } 
                        echo ($html_body);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    echo "Says it's not writable: ".$dest_dir;
                }
            }
            else{//not a directory?
                echo "Says it's not a directory:".$dest_dir;
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "No file POSTED.\n";
        }
    }
```

The only error that I get is from $_FILES['Filedata']['error'] = 3, 'Only part of the file was uploaded'. The destination directory does have 777 permission and you can see I made the required checks. It simply will not work, I have no idea why. Also, the files I tried uploading had no spaces in the filename, so that shouldn't fit under the issue 206 with SWFUpload.

As far as I can tell it can be either due to the front-end SWFUpload or back-end server configuration. Please help.

P.S. no need to mention security, this is only allowed to be used by the server admin with external access anyhow, plus there's the front-end limitation on the files he can select (images). There was no point securing it further.

Comment: How large is the file you're uploading? Also do this :>`echo ini_get("upload_max_filesize");`

Comment: the ones I tried were around 200kB. Okay I'll try it now, thanks.

Comment: The error number `3` happens when upload was somehow interrupted.

Comment: How is the question though :(

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was with the SWFUpload itself, it simply failed when used with linux servers. To anyone who has similar problems, consider using [this](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) instead:

ridiculously easy to adapt, works out of the box and you can customize it to your hearts content with ease. 
I implemented all I wanted in under 20 minutes, it's a pure delight to use and works well. Beautifully designed.

Comment: swfupload works fine with linux servers. Please do not blame the tool because it is not working in your case.

Comment: @Nisk it works on all systems out of the box because i've used it on all systems.

Comment: well, want to tell me why it doesn't work in this case? Go on. Please.

Comment: From the code listed in OP alone it's pretty hard to tell why your server interrupts the download and the whole point of using SWFUpload over HTML5 is that the progress bar will work in older browsers that don't support AJAX2

Comment: No. The front-end code above works, this I know for a fact because it worked fine on a windows host. The backend-code makes all the necessary checks and gives an error that quite plainly says "file wasn't fully uploaded". It kind of obvious what the faulty component is, SWFUpload. Unless you want to lay the blame on my hosting provider and their servers (or Apache?). To be fair, it is possible the problem is not so much with SWFUpload (which is still far from good, either way) but the flash as it is available on the linux platform. Fact is, we don't know what's going wrong, I wish I did.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is actually server configuration.  Since built-in PHP does not support putting together partial uploads, you must implicitly tell the browser you don't support them!

Here are a few options:

- Configure webserver to send the header "Allow-Ranges: none" for all PHP requests.
- Implicitly close the connection after each upload.  Add `header('Connection: close');` to the server side script.
- Turn KeepAlives off.